# pyspark: how to free resources

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm executing this code inside IPython Notebook

```
def some():
    import pyspark
    conf = (pyspark.SparkConf() 
                    .setMaster("yarn-client") 
                    .setAppName("MyTest")) 
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
    data = sc.textFile("/tmp/mytest/")
    print data.count()

some()
```

I'm exepecting Spark to free resources after the execution of function some() ends (executors and driver should exit). However it doesn't happen. Application terminates only when I close my Notebook.

Could anyone give me a clue of how to terminate a pyspark application from within my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is garbage collected, you shouldn't worry much about resources - *memory* anyway.

But you can always use `sc.stop()`, which is handy for several other cases, as well.